# Как вписать фотографию без нарушения пропорций в блок с резиновой шириной?

Tags: html, css, img

Как вписать фотографию, занимающую две трети ширины так, чтобы обрезалась
сверху и снизу при увеличении размера (ширина 66%, высота подстраивается под ширину,**чтобы не нарушать пропорций**, но фото не выходит за отведённую для него зону).

Нашел как вариант свойство: **object-fit: cover;**

Из минусов не поддерживает IE. Может есть еще варианты решения?

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 3px solid black;
}

.wrap div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrap img{
  width: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468428936365-099c2f70e495?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=7ffde0607b4ab9dd2faeb50bbf39ff03" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 3px solid black;
}

.wrap .block {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrap .image {
  width: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
}

.image {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468428936365-099c2f70e495?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=7ffde0607b4ab9dd2faeb50bbf39ff03);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант хорошее решение. 
Только я искал для встроенного фото (img).

Comment: Я не уверен что это можно так хорошо реализовать как с background

Answer (score 0):

Можно ставить ее вертикально по центру:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrap img{
  width: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468428936365-099c2f70e495?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=7ffde0607b4ab9dd2faeb50bbf39ff03" alt="">
</div>
```

Только сама картинка резаться будет только по блоку, если нужно резать по высоте, то можно засунут